# execution frequency of header of a loop

Tags: optimization, compiler-construction, llvm

In a LLVM pass, I'd like to record the loop trip count of a loop. One part I did was inserting a function call before the terminator of the header block of each loop. I found that this method did not work well, because if a loop has n iterations, the header block will be executed n+1 times. This fact holds for "for" and "while" loop, but it does not hold for "do while" loop. I insert the function call to the second block of "for" and "while" loops, and to the first block of "do while" loops. This works only if I know a priori the kind the targeted loop, which is impossible through purely bitcode. My question is: is there a universal way (handling all kinds of loops) to insert a function call, which will be called exactly the same times as the number of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Put the function call at the start of the body of the loop. Why are you trying to put it in the header?

```
for (...) {
  increment_trip_count();
  ...
}
```

Comment: How can I know which basic block is the beginning block of the loop body? I tested and see that in many cases loop header block is the same as the first basic block contained by the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you insert the function call in the beginning of the loop body, you will get the correct count.

Comment: The problem is how to know the beginning block of loop body.

Comment: The loop body is the part that typically is placed inside braces. If you place your call to your function there, it will tell you how many times the body is being executed, and that is what you asked for, wasn't it?

Comment: In source code level, it is surely correct. However, my question is specific to llvm. The loop structure in llvm has a list of basic blocks. However, the first block will be executed n + 1 times, where n is the loop trip count of the loop. This holds for "for" and "while" loops, but it is not true for "do while" loops, in which the first block will be executed n times.

Comment: Ah, you're talking of inserting the call in the immediate format that the llvm emits. In that light, you could safely ignore my answer as I assumed it was a general programming question. Please state special circumstances like this your questions, to avoid similar misunderstandings in the future.